# Section numbers do not display correctly when Hebrew is loaded as other language by polyglossia

Tags: koma-script, appendices, hebrew, bidi

I am using the `polyglossia` package to write a document which contains English text and a few Hebrew names. There seems to be problem with `bidi` and `scrbook` as soon there is an appendix. In this case the name of the first chapter in the document is ".1 Chapter One" instead of "1 Chapter One" or "1. Chapter One". How can this be fixed?

Please find below a MWE to reproduce this problem.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{UKenglish}
\setotherlanguages{russian, hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

\section{Section One}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```